# Starting XL Deploy: Unsupported Class version error

Tags: xl-deploy

When starting XL Deploy 8.1.0 using the command: run.cmd -setup. I got the below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/xebialabs
/deployit/DeployitBootstrapper : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
```

My computer installed java 8 and using Windows 7 Professional, do you know how to fix this ?

```
java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. My variable "JAVA_HOME" is setting to JDK7, so I changed it to JDK8 (in Environment Variable setting) and it ok